# Changing textBox.text from event handler

Tags: c#, events, serial-port, handler

Can't seem to find an answer here for the life of me..
Anyhow, how can an event handler change Form's textBox.text?

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            //Do what ever you want with the data
            textBox2.Text = "test"; //alas, this doesn't work
        }
```

The event handler is created when a button is pressed

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
                    serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
                    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
                    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                    serialPort1.Open();
                }
            }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you better describe the behavior?

Comment: Also, **be careful** when subscribing to events programatically. If you were to click `button3` 2 times, your code for `DataReceivedHandler` will be called 2 times as well!

Comment: The `DataReceived` event is raised in a secondary thread. `BeginInvoke`, to change a `TextBox.Text` in the UI thread.

Comment: It doesn't work as in the syntax is invalid (an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.textBox2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataReceivedHandler` method is marked `static`, so it cannot access the instance member `textBox2`. Does removing `static` solve the problem?

Comment: Although the syntax is now correct it throws an exception on runtime
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: Re-read my comment under the question: you need to `BeginInvoke` the UI Thread: `this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { textBox2.Text = "test"; }));`

Answer (score 0):

The `DataReceived` is on it's own thread, you'll need to invoke the GUI in order to update the textbox.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox2.AppendText(Data);
    });
}
```